# Kubernetes Pod - HTTP not working inside (curl)

Tags: docker, http, kubernetes, grafana

When trying to curl http://google.de it doesn't work. But when i try https://google.de, i get an answer.

```
# HTTPS
root@grafana-77798b4bf9-jhn2z:/usr/share/grafana# curl https://google.de
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.de/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

# HTTP
root@grafana-77798b4bf9-jhn2z:/usr/share/grafana# curl -v http://google.de
*   Trying 216.58.213.195:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4005:803::2003:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4005:803::2003: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4005:803::2003:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4005:803::2003: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4005:803::2003:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:4005:803::2003: Cannot assign requested address
^C
```

Does somebody else, have similar result?
Image: grafana/grafana:latest-ubuntu

Running a 2 Node Cluster (1 Master, 1 Worker). Both on Debian Buster

```
Linux kubernetes-master 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux kubernetes-slave 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1+deb9u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Whats the output of `curl https://google.de -v` ? also try `curl http://google.de -4`

Comment: Here https://pastebin.com/y6b8r07j
Really suspicious behaviour, never seen something like this

Comment: Looks like https is using ipv4 and http is using ipv6 for some reason. I have no idea why this happens but probably you don't have interface with ipv6 address and thus the error.

Comment: Yes, but HTTP is using IPv4 too (with -4) but i get timeoutted. We disabled IPv6 in our Network. https://pastebin.com/NZEhAkMK

Comment: maybe the firewall is blocking port 80

Comment: What is the output of `traceroute google.de 80`?

Comment: Firewall cant be blocking port 80, because other Docker Images and normal Clients are working fine. I cant test traceroute from inside the Container because there is no package for it and i cant install it. Because apt update is failing because of this.
This is a traceroute from my Client, own IP is redacted - https://pastebin.com/r8fztc7X

Comment: Are you using k8s network policies?

Comment: Did you try deleting the pod so it gets rescheduled on different node? or did you try curling different domain?

Comment: nope, not using network policies. :) yes, already tried and did that. i tried deleting, redeploying (e.g. patch new deployment)

Comment: Try `imagePullPolicy: Always` to force a pull or try rebooting the node.

Comment: Sorry for not answering so long, imagePullPolicy is default in our manifests. Rebooting the node is the next thing I'm trying, trying that this evening.